# Java Android OTG Cable Detect

Tags: android

How to turn switch on inside android app when OTG Cable is plugged inside micro Usb port and turn switch off when OTG cable is plugged out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The cable is just an extension of the leads that are already in the plug. If something is plugged into the cable, then something could be detected, but the cable alone? not possible.

Comment: But how can this app detect OTG Cable : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homesoft.otgtroubshooter

Comment: From the description on that page "Required hardware: 2. A flash/pen drive, card reader or camera." << there must be a device plugged into the cable

Comment: I tried only to insert cable without anything on it and app has detected it!

Comment: How to make otg cable detect like in that app?